# How to setup aws instance to listen to the requests?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, service, mqtt, mosquitto

I am setting a service **Mosquitto broker** starting at port **1883**. I have a local client that connects to the service general syntax is :

```
protocol://url:port
```

I have tried url parameter with following parameters

*1.IP*

```
tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1883
```

**Result:Failed.
 Reason:Connection Timeout**

*2.public dns*

```
tcp://dnsgivenbyamazon:1883
```

**Result: Failed
Reason: Connection Timeout**

*3.ethernet address:*

```
tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1883
```

**Result: Failed
Reason:Connection timeout**

I also enabled port in *firewall*:

```
sudo ufw allow 1883/tcp
```

I also manually set rules for the port in *security-group*

What I am missing what is the correct parameter I should try connecting to?

Comment: Have you tried with something else first? Like netcat? `nc -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80`
Are you sure about security groups? Usually if you correctly open them you should at least get `Connection refused`

Comment: @Yudi First check the security groups and disable the firewall.

Comment: @Hussain Isnt that would be a security vulnerability

Comment: @alex88 nc worked :) good for testing I am able to connect now. It saves time.

Comment: @Yudi Security Groups takes care of it. Host firewall is an additional level of security so basically, it depends on the use-cases.

Comment: Thanks Hussain.  nc -v x.x.x.x 1883 success but when with different port nc -c x.x.x.x 8881 Connection Timeout not refused @alex88

Comment: @Yudi Make sure your instance security group allows just your desired port, in this case it is 1883, that way nc can connect only to 1883 if there is a process running on the port, else nc connection is refused by the firewall